# Syntax for multiple function calls in one line - Haskell

Tags: haskell

This may be really straightforward but I'm new to Haskell and have no idea what I'm doing.

I have three functions:

```
first :: (Int, [Char], [[Char]], [((Int,Int),(Int,Int))]) -> (Int, [Char], [[Char]])
first (a, arr, stringlist, []) = (a, arr, stringlist)
first (a, arr, stringlist, (x:xs))
    | snd(snd(x)) == 1 = (first $ (second (a, arr, stringlist)) xs)
    | otherwise = (first $ (third (a arr stringlist x)) xs)

second :: (Int, [Char], [[Char]]) -> (Int, [Char], [[Char]])

third :: (Int, [Char], [[Char]], ((Int,Int),(Int,Int))) -> (Int, [Char], [[Char]])
```

Second and third both work so the details of those don't matter.
I'm sure there are multiple errors in my implementation of first but the part that says

```
(first $ (second (a, arr, stringlist)) xs)
```

is my main issue.  What is the proper way to call second and then pass the result and the tail of the list to first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely consider some type aliases, or even better use [record syntax](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax) to simplify your type signatures.  You can also get rid of a lot of those parentheses:

```
first :: (Int, [Char], [[Char]], [((Int,Int),(Int,Int))]) -> (Int, [Char], [[Char]])
first (a, arr, stringlist, []) = (a, arr, stringlist)
first (a, arr, stringlist, (x:xs))
    | snd (snd x) == 1 = first $ (second (a, arr, stringlist)) xs
    | otherwise = first $ (third $ a arr stringlist x) xs
```

And I think this makes it easier to see that your syntax is a bit wrong.  What you have is passing the argument `xs` to `second (a, arr, stringlist)`, which does not return a function so it will result in an error, and similarly with the second case.  If you changed it to this, it would be closer to correct.

```
first :: (Int, [Char], [[Char]], [((Int,Int),(Int,Int))]) -> (Int, [Char], [[Char]])
first (a, arr, stringlist, []) = (a, arr, stringlist)
first (a, arr, stringlist, (x:xs))
    | snd (snd x) == 1 = first (second (a, arr, stringlist)) xs
    | otherwise = first (third $ a arr stringlist x) xs
```

I also see that you're passing 4 arguments to `third`, when it should be taking a 4-tuple, so maybe something like

```
first :: (Int, [Char], [[Char]], [((Int,Int),(Int,Int))]) -> (Int, [Char], [[Char]])
first (a, arr, stringlist, []) = (a, arr, stringlist)
first (a, arr, stringlist, (x:xs))
    | snd (snd x) == 1 = first (second (a, arr, stringlist)) xs
    | otherwise = first (third (a, arr, stringlist, x)) xs
```

Now we get to the problem that you're passing two arguments to `first` when you only want one argument.  You have something of type `(Int, [Char], [[Char]])` and something else of type `[((Int, Int), (Int, Int))]`, and you want to combine them into a 4-tuple.  I would suggest making an auxiliary function to do just that:

```
mk4from3 :: (a, b, c) -> d -> (a, b, c, d)
mk4from3 (a, b, c) d = (a, b, c, d)
```

Then you can simply write

```
first :: (Int, [Char], [[Char]], [((Int,Int),(Int,Int))]) -> (Int, [Char], [[Char]])
first (a, arr, stringlist, []) = (a, arr, stringlist)
first (a, arr, stringlist, (x:xs))
    | snd (snd x) == 1 = first $ mk4from3 (second (a, arr, stringlist)) xs
    | otherwise = first $ mk4from3 (third (a, arr, stringlist, x)) xs
```

---

The general rule of thumb I use when deciding if I should convert a tuple into its own data type is if I use a 3-tuple or larger in more than one type signature, I should make it a data type, even if it isn't using record syntax and instead just uses ADT features.